# Java Spring RMI Activation

Tags: java, spring, rmi, activation

As I understand, spring has a nice framework for RMI that looks like its still using the old school UnicastRemoteObject class. What if i wanted to use Activation instead, does spring support this? I havn't found any documents to support this? I am confused if this is actually implementable through spring?? Also just to mention, the rmid is another daemon needed. Does spring deal with this at all? Also from anyone elses experience, what would be the best way to use Activation and incorporate Spring?

Comment: You would be one of very few people in the world using RMI Activation if you succeeded. It works, but there is no proper security model around it (e.g. no SSL access to `rmid`, and a host of trust relationships between you and it and the activated objects that are just taken for granted). Can't recommend you pursue this line.

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't support RMI activation.  [Spring includes an `RmiServiceExporter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/rmi/RmiServiceExporter.html) for calling remote objects that contains nice improvements over standard RMI, such as not requiring that services extend `java.rmi.Remote`.

This being said, why are you interested in RMI activation, as opposed to a RESTful web service instead?

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, much appreciated. I am working on some old legacy code from the early 2000's at work. It is setup using RMI Activation and i was looking to update it with newer technologies. It is a fairly large project so I am not so keen on changed the technology and architecture too much unless its a fairly easy transition and doesn't take too much time.