# How to integrate a Spring RMI server with a pure Java RMI client which is a non-spring Swing GUI?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, jndi, rmi

I'm migrating a J2EE EJB application to Spring services. It's a desktop application which has a Swing GUI and to communicate to the J2EE server it uses RMI. I have created a simple spring service with spring boot which exports a service by using spring remoting, RMIServiceExporter. The client is a rich client and have a complicated architecture so i'm trying make minimum changes to it to call the spring rmi service.

So in summary I have a plain RMI client and a spring RMI server. I have learned that spring rmi abstracts pure java rmi so in my case they don't interoperate.

I will show the code below but the current error is this. Note that my current project uses "remote://". So after I have got this error I have also tried "rmi://". But, in both cases it gives this error.

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [rmi://yyy:1099 (No connection provider for URI scheme "rmi" is installed)]
                at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.failOverSequence(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:244)
                at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingStore(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:149)
                at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:130)
                at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.lookup(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:272)
                at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookupInternal(RemoteContext.java:104)
                at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:93)
                at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:146)
                at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
                at com.xxx.ui.common.communication.JbossRemotingInvocationFactory.getRemoteObject(JbossRemotingInvocationFactory.java:63)
                at com.xxx.gui.comm.CommManager.initializeSpringEJBz(CommManager.java:806)
                at com.xxx.gui.comm.CommManager.initializeEJBz(CommManager.java:816)
                at com.xxx.gui.comm.CommManager.initializeAndLogin(CommManager.java:373)
                at com.xxx.gui.comm.CommManager$2.doInBackground(CommManager.java:273)
                at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have searched for how we can interoperate spring rmi and plain/pure java rmi and i read several answers from similar questions at stackoverflow and web but i couldn't find anything useful or fits my case because even the best matched answer says only that it doesn't interoperate.

I thought that maybe i need to turn my swing gui client to spring by using spring boot but i couldn't be sure about application context since i don't want to break existing client code. So i have looked for maybe there is something like partial spring context so that maybe i can put only my CommManager.java client code to it and spring only manages this file.

And then I thought that maybe I need to change my RMI server to force spring to create some kind of plain/pure Java RMI instead of default spring RMI thing. I say thing because I read something about spring rmi that explains it's an abstraction over rmi and we can force it to create standard RMI stub.

While I'm searching for a solution i have encountered the Spring Integration but I couldn't understand it really since it looks like an other abstraction but it also tell something about adapters. Since I have seen "adapter" maybe it is used for this kind of integration/legacy code migration cases. But I couldn't go further.

**Client Side:**

CommManager.java

```
private boolean initializeEJBz(String userName, String password) throws Exception {
        ...
        ri = RemoteInvocationFactory.getRemoteInvocation(user, pass);
        if (ri != null) {
            return initializeEJBz(ri);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

RemoteInvocationFactory.java

```
package com.xxx.ui.common.communication;

import javax.naming.NamingException;

public final class RemoteInvocationFactory {
    private static final CommunicationProperties cp = new CommunicationProperties();

    public static synchronized RemoteInvocation getRemoteInvocation(
            byte[] userName, byte[] password) throws NamingException {
        String url = System.getProperty("rmi://xxx.com:1099");
        if (url != null) {
            return new JbossRemotingInvocationFactory(userName, password, url);
        }
        return null;
    }
...
```

JbossRemotingInvocationFactory.java

```
package com.xxx.ui.common.communication;

...
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
...
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class JbossRemotingInvocationFactory implements RemoteInvocation {
    private final byte[] userName, password;
    private final String providerURL;
    private volatile InitialContext initialContext;
    private final SecretKey secretKey;
    private static final String SSL_ENABLED = "jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED";
    private static final String SSL_STARTTLS = "jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_STARTTLS";
    private static final String TIMEOUT = "jboss.naming.client.connect.timeout";

    private long timeoutValue;
    private final boolean startSsl;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public JbossRemotingInvocationFactory(byte[] userName, byte[] password, String providerURL) {
        try {
            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            keyGenerator.init(128);
            secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
            this.providerURL = providerURL;
            startSsl = Boolean.valueOf(System.getProperty(SSL_ENABLED));
            String property = System.getProperty("myproject.connect.timeout");
            if (property != null) {
                try {
                    timeoutValue = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(Long.parseLong(property), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    timeoutValue = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
            }
            Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
            this.userName = encrypt(userName);
            addOptions(jndiProperties);
            jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, new String(password, UTF_8));
            initialContext = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
            this.password = encrypt(password);
        } catch (NamingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException ne) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ne);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T getRemoteObject(Class<T> object, String jndiName) throws NamingException {
        if (initialContext != null) {
            T value = (T) initialContext.lookup(jndiName);
            initialContext.removeFromEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS);
            initialContext.removeFromEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL);
            return value;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T getRemoteObject(Class<T> object) throws NamingException {
        throw new IllegalAccessError();
    }

    ...


    private void addOptions(Hashtable jndiProperties) {
        jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", "true");
        jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "false");
        jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
        jndiProperties.put(SSL_STARTTLS, "false");
        jndiProperties.put(TIMEOUT, Long.toString(timeoutValue));
        if (startSsl) {
            jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "true");
            jndiProperties.put(SSL_ENABLED, "true");
        }
        jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_DISALLOWED_MECHANISMS", "JBOSS-LOCAL-USER");
        jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerURL);
        jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, new String(decrypt(userName), UTF_8));
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnect() {
        try {
            Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
            addOptions(jndiProperties);
            jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, new String(decrypt(password), UTF_8));
            initialContext = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
        } catch (NamingException ignore) {
        }
    }
}
```

CommManager.java

```
private boolean initializeEJBz(RemoteInvocation remoteInvocation) throws Exception {
        cs = remoteInvocation.getRemoteObject(CustomerService.class, JNDINames.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_REMOTE);
       ...

        // here is the integration point. try to get RMI service exported.
        myService = remoteInvocation.getRemoteObject(HelloWorldRMI.class, JNDINames.HELLO_WORLD_REMOTE);


        return true;
}
```

```
public static final String CUSTOMER_SERVICE_REMOTE = getRemoteBean("CustomerServiceBean", CustomerService.class.getName());

public static final string HELLO_WORLD_REMOTE = getRemoteBean("HelloWorldRMI", HelloWorldRMI.class.getName());

...

private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "XXX";
private static final String MODULE_NAME = "YYYY";

...

protected static String getRemoteBean(String beanName, String interfaceName) {
        return String.format("%s/%s/%s!%s", APPLICATION_NAME, MODULE_NAME, beanName, interfaceName);
    }
```

**Server Side:**

HelloWorldRMI.java:

```
package com.example.springrmiserver.service;

public interface HelloWorldRMI {
    public String sayHelloRmi(String msg);
}
```

HelloWorldRMIImpl:

```
package com.example.springrmiserver.service;

import java.util.Date;

public class HelloWorldRMIimpl implements HelloWorldRMI {

    @Override
    public String sayHelloRmi(String msg) {
        System.out.println("================Server Side ========================");
        System.out.println("Inside Rmi IMPL - Incoming msg : " + msg);
        return "Hello " + msg + " :: Response time - > " + new Date();
    }
}
```

Config.java:

```
package com.example.springrmiserver;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter;
import org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteExporter;

import com.example.springrmiserver.service.HelloWorldRMI;
import com.example.springrmiserver.service.HelloWorldRMIimpl;

@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    RemoteExporter registerRMIExporter() {

        RmiServiceExporter exporter = new RmiServiceExporter();
        exporter.setServiceName("helloworldrmi");
        //exporter.setRegistryPort(1190);
        exporter.setServiceInterface(HelloWorldRMI.class);
        exporter.setService(new HelloWorldRMIimpl());

        return exporter;
    }


}
```

SpringServerApplication.java:

```
package com.example.springrmiserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.util.Collections;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringRmiServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //SpringApplication.run(SpringRmiServerApplication.class, args);
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(SpringRmiServerApplication.class);
        app.setDefaultProperties(Collections.singletonMap("server.port", "8084"));
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

So, my problem is how to interoperate pure/plain/standard java rmi client which is in a swing GUI with spring rmi server?

**Edit #1:**

By the way if you can provide further explanations or links about internal details of spring RMI stub creation and why they don't interoperate i will be happy. Thanks indeed.

And also, if you look at my getRemoteBean method which is from legacy code, how does this lookup string works? I mean where does rmi registry file or something resides at server or is this the default format or can i customize it?

**Edit #2:**
I have also tried this kind of lookup in the client:

```
private void initializeSpringEJBz(RemoteInvocation remoteInvocation) throws Exception {
    HelloWorldRMI helloWorldService = (HelloWorldRMI) Naming.lookup("rmi://xxx:1099/helloworldrmi");
    System.out.println("Output" + helloWorldService.sayHelloRmi("hello "));
    //hw = remoteInvocation.getRemoteObject(HelloWorldRMI.class, "helloworldrmi");
}
```

**Edit #3:**

While I'm searching i found that someone in a spring forum suggested that to force spring to create plain java rmi stub we have to make some changes on the server side so i have tried this:

```
import java.rmi.server.RemoteObject;

public interface HelloWorldRMI extends **Remote** {
   public String sayHelloRmi(String msg) throws **RemoteException**;
   ...
}

...

public class HelloWorldRMIimpl extends **RemoteObject** implements HelloWorldRMI {
...
}
```

Is the code above on the right path to solve the problem?

Beside that the first problem is the connection setup as you can see in the beginning of the question. Why i'm getting this error? What is the difference between "rmi://" and "remote://" ?

Comment: You can't. You will have to use Spring at the client.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @user207421 but in the interest of full disclosure i have tried to give details in the question to ask what possibilities available to achieve this. So in the question i have also asked is it possible to make my client partially spring based i.e only the CommManager uses spring. As you said if it is possible only by making my client to use spring, how can i achieve this partially? In this context maybe it is more appropriate to ask another question but i'm just trying to use spring's only rmi functionality in the client.

Comment: Either it uses Spring RMI or it doesn't. I don't see how 'partially' can come into it.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't state it clearly. What i mean is that is it possible in this case to set up the application context of the spring to be used only by the CommManager not the whole GUI client i.e. main method? So that i can use Spring to only manage CommManager by injecting RMI related beans.

Answer (score 1):

While I was trying to figure out, I could be able to find a solution. It's true that Spring RMI and Java RMI do not interoperate but currently i don't have enough knowledge to explain its cause. I couldn't find any complete explanation about internals of this mismatch yet.

The solution is using plain Java RMI in Spring backend by using `java.rmi.*(Remote, RemoteException and server.UnicastRemoteObject)`.

> java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject is used for exporting a remote object with Java Remote Method Protocol (JRMP) and obtaining a stub that communicates to the remote object.

**Edit:**
I think this post is closely related to this interoperability issue: [Java Spring RMI Activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257522/java-spring-rmi-activation)

> Spring doesn't support RMI activation. Spring includes an RmiServiceExporter for calling remote objects that contains nice improvements over standard RMI, such as not requiring that services extend java.rmi.Remote.

**Solution:**

This is the interface that server exports:

```
package com.xxx.ejb.interf;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface HelloWorldRMI extends Remote {
    public String sayHelloRmi(String msg) throws RemoteException;
}
```

and this is the implementation of exported class:

```
package com.xxx.proxyserver.service;

import com.xxx.ejb.interf.HelloWorldRMI;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.Date;

public class HelloWorldRMIimpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements HelloWorldRMI {

    public HelloWorldRMIimpl() throws RemoteException{
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHelloRmi(String msg) {
        System.out.println("================Server Side ========================");
        System.out.println("Inside Rmi IMPL - Incoming msg : " + msg);
        return "Hello " + msg + " :: Response time - > " + new Date();
    }
}
```

and the RMI Registry is:

```
package com.xxx.proxyserver;

import com.xxx.proxyserver.service.CustomerServiceImpl;
import com.xxx.proxyserver.service.HelloWorldRMIimpl;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.util.Collections;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProxyServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1200); // this line of code automatic creates a new RMI-Registry. Existing one can be also reused.
        System.out.println("Registry created !");

        registry.rebind("just_an_alias",new HelloWorldRMIimpl());
        registry.rebind("path/to/service_as_registry_key/CustomerService", new CustomerServiceImpl());

        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ProxyServerApplication.class);
        app.setDefaultProperties(Collections.singletonMap("server.port", "8084")); // Service port
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
...
   HelloWorldRMI helloWorldService = (HelloWorldRMI)Naming.lookup("rmi://st-spotfixapp1:1200/just_an_alias");
   System.out.println("Output" + helloWorldService.sayHelloRmi("hello from client ... "));
...
```